Check if any system app is running in fullscreen nodeJS
I'm making this widget in electron that shows up on the screen when you press ctrl+space.
I only want the widget be able to show up when there's no app running in fullscreen mode.
I've tried using powershell but that doesn't seem to work
const { exec } = require('child_process')
function isFullscreenAppRunning() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = `
        function Is-AppFullScreen {
                param(
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
                [string] $ProcessName
                )
            
                # Get main screen resolution
                $screenWidth = (Get-Screen).WorkingArea.Width
                $screenHeight = (Get-Screen).WorkingArea.Height
            
                # Get window of the process
                $window = Get-Process -Name $ProcessName | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne $null} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle
            
                if ($window) {
                # Get window dimensions (accounting for borders)
                $windowRect = [System.Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB((Get-Window -Handle $window).Left, (Get-Window -Handle $window).Top, (Get-Window -Handle $window).Right, (Get-Window -Handle $window).Bottom)
                $windowWidth = $windowRect.Width - (Get-Window -Handle $window).BorderWidth
                $windowHeight = $windowRect.Height - (Get-Window -Handle $window).BorderHeight
            
                # Check if window dimensions match screen resolution (considering potential rounding errors)
                return ($windowWidth -eq $screenWidth -and $windowHeight -eq $screenHeight)
                } else {
                # Process not found or no main window
                return $false
                }
            }
            
            # Check all processes with a main window title
            $isAnyAppFullScreen = $false
            Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne $null} | ForEach-Object {
                $processName = $_.Name
                if (Is-AppFullScreen -ProcessName $processName) {
                $isAnyAppFullScreen = $true
                # Exit loop once a fullscreen app is found (optional for performance)
                break
                }
            }
            
            # Return true if any app is fullscreen, false otherwise
            return $isAnyAppFullScreen
            `
        
        exec(`powershell -command "${script}"`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
            reject(err)
            return
            }
            resolve(stdout.trim() === 'True')
        })
    })
}


There is a fullscreen pseudo selector, so maybe you can :not() it see :fullscreen

Solved by running a discrete C# script that returns either True or False
depending on if a focused window is running in Full-Screen mode.
A function in NodeJS runs this script and listens for data output from the file (checkFullscreen.exe).

You can also try these code
Add-Type @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Win32 {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }
    }
"@

function IsAppFullScreen {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $ProcessName
    )

    $processes = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -ne "" }

    foreach ($process in $processes) {
        $handle = $process.MainWindowHandle
        $rect = New-Object Win32.RECT

        if (-not [Win32]::GetWindowRect($handle, [ref]$rect)) {
            continue
        }

        $width = $rect.Right - $rect.Left
        $height = $rect.Bottom - $rect.Top

        $screenWidth = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
        $screenHeight = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height

        if ($width -eq $screenWidth -and $height -eq $screenHeight) {
            return $true
        }
    }

    return $false
}

# Check if any app is fullscreen
$isAnyAppFullScreen = $false
$isAnyAppFullScreen = IsAppFullScreen

# Return true if any app is fullscreen, false otherwise
$isAnyAppFullScreen

and NodeJs
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function isFullscreenAppRunning() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = `
            function Is-AppFullScreen {
                param(
                    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
                    [string] $ProcessName
                )
                
                # Get main screen resolution
                $screenWidth = (Get-WmiObject Win32_DesktopMonitor).ScreenWidth
                $screenHeight = (Get-WmiObject Win32_DesktopMonitor).ScreenHeight
                
                # Get window of the process
                $window = Get-Process -Name $ProcessName | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne $null} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle
                
                if ($window) {
                    # Get window dimensions (accounting for borders)
                    $windowRect = [System.Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB((Get-Window -Handle $window).Left, (Get-Window -Handle $window).Top, (Get-Window -Handle $window).Right, (Get-Window -Handle $window).Bottom)
                    $windowWidth = $windowRect.Width - (Get-Window -Handle $window).BorderWidth
                    $windowHeight = $windowRect.Height - (Get-Window -Handle $window).BorderHeight
                    
                    # Check if window dimensions match screen resolution (considering potential rounding errors)
                    return ($windowWidth -eq $screenWidth -and $windowHeight -eq $screenHeight)
                } else {
                    # Process not found or no main window
                    return $false
                }
            }
            
            # Check all processes with a main window title
            $isAnyAppFullScreen = $false
            Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne $null} | ForEach-Object {
                $processName = $_.Name
                if (Is-AppFullScreen -ProcessName $processName) {
                    $isAnyAppFullScreen = $true
                    # Exit loop once a fullscreen app is found (optional for performance)
                    break
                }
            }
            
            # Return true if any app is fullscreen, false otherwise
            return $isAnyAppFullScreen
        `;
        
        exec(`powershell -command "${script}"`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(stdout.trim() === 'True');
        });
    });
}

// Usage
isFullscreenAppRunning().then(result => {
    console.log('Is any app running in fullscreen?', result);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});


What language is this? The original question is for electron/node

The PowerShell code you provided, which originally used PowerShell and C# libraries, has been modified to include Node.js.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The powershell script you shared is asking for a process name, i don't want this. I simply want the script to go through all of the apps the user currently has open and if one of these apps are runnig in fullscreen mode meaning the taskbar is not visible, that's when i want my widget to not show

This is a JS job, not node.js...
// Detect when a frame/window is in/out of full screen

W.contentWindow.visualViewport.onresize=function(e){

 if((W.offsetWidth*W.offsetHeight)==(screen.availWidth*screen.availHeight)){

  // gone full screen    

 } else {

  // exited full screen

 }

};

NB: "W" is the frame/window you're operating on. To use this code in your own document replace "W.contentWindow" with just "window".
More visualViewport info...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

But isn't this just checking if my electron window is running in fullscreen? I don't want that, I think you misunderstood my question.
